# Should I upload the gulpfile.js, package.json and source files to production?

Tags: node.js, dev-to-production

I am hosting my website on GitHub. I am using npm and Gulp.

Should I upload my `package.json` file, the `gupfile.js` and the `build/` folder (CSS and JS source files) to my production server?

Comment: It's ok to upload package.json file but gulpfile.js is used for development purpose.

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani What about the folder with the CSS source files?

Comment: Yes, these folder are must for a website application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for a production environment, you do not upload the gulpfile.js to the production server unless there is a specific task you have written that pertains only to your production environment. Your build folder would get uploaded along with your package.json, since then all you will need to do on your production server once the app is uploaded would be to `npm install` and then start your server.

I know it wasn't a part of your question, but since you are on the topic of putting an app into production, I would highly suggest using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to run your application. It's really friendly with node. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep! Glad I could help!